# Creating a Fake Computer Screen Within a Screen in Website

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've begun working on a website for a grant-funded documentary. Within the documentary, one of the characters is building a website about a topic. For the real website, tthey want to put his computer (which is an hand-drawn graphic by the project's artist) around the website design & content as a frame.

To put it another way, when a user visits the actual website, they'll see the character's "screen" with the real design inside of it. In way, it's simulating a computer with a web design inside of my proper web design.

Cue "Inception" score.

Alright, now for the fun part. How in the heck would *you* go about this? I need to:

1. Maximize screen real estate within the frame, obviously. However, I also need a way for the whole kit and caboodle to resize well for different monitors.
2. Create this thing in such a way that it loads posts and videos well. In essence, I need it to not be sloppy on every device it encounters. Obviously, I'll ditch the concept for mobile, so just talking desktop.

I also have to do it all in **WordPress**, specifically using Genesis.

Let me know what you think! jQuery is more than acceptable here if it helps, as is any hair-brained idea you have.

Thanks!

/***EDIT #3 -- Solved***/

**Link to site is: 
http://www.blackbirdsfell.com**

Comment: Than, to build it for mobile... will be a nightmare. *"Maximize screen real estate within the frame"* ...do you have a graphic to show? Have you tried to start code anything?

Comment: Are you asking for this? You could do it with css images. http://tutorializing.com/images/tutorials/code/css/css_vignette/css3-vignette-battle-plan.jpg

Comment: Sorry, should have posted a graphic! Here's a (very rough) version of the general idea. Actual website needs to sit inside that frame. Tricky bit is that, since it's hand-drawn art (and more or less needs to stay that way) it's non-repeatable and not easily fit into a lot of frameworks I'd usually use. 

http://imgur.com/mbYPHZp

Comment: Just posted an update to the problem. Any thoughts, guys? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing F11 in most browsers enters full screen mode. This will hide both the task bar and the browser URL bar.

In order to create everything else just use several DIVS. 1 div for the url bar, 3 divs for the centre. 1 being in the center(this the website design) and the other 2 on either side creating the computer effect and the last div below. This would be the task bar. Set all your sizes in percentages and make the width 100%. This will make it easily and quickly fit on all monitor sizes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top_bar">INSERT TOP PART OF THE COMPUTER SCREEN</div> 
<div id="left_bar">INSERT LEFT PART OF THE COMPUTER SCREEN"</div> 
<div id="main">INSERT WEB DESIGN"</div> 
<div id="right_bar">INSERT RIGHT PART OF THE COMPUTER SCREEN"</div> 
<div id="bottom_bar">INSERT BOTTOM PART OF THE COMPUTER SCREEN"</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
#top_bar{ width:100%; } 
#left_bar{ float: left; width: 20%; } 
#main{ float: left; width: 60%; } 
#right_bar{ float: left; width: 20%; } 
#bottom_bar { width: 100%; position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

The percentages will not be correct. This will be something that you will have to play around with until it fits correctly.

The `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` will force the bottom bar to always stay exactly at the bottom. I presume this will help sell the effect and so added that too.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Looks promising, and very well laid out. Just to be specific, this would be a good fit for Genesis' wraps and such? The site is here: 

http://www.blackbirdsfell.com

And the general graphic would look something like this: 

http://imgur.com/mbYPHZp

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah this would fit that idea perfectly and would be the simplest way of doing it. The computer graphic would need to be cut into 4 separate images. The top, the left and right segment and then the bottom. It is similar to the genesis wrap but not exactly the same. In genesis there is not 3 editable sections in the middle. I'll edit above post to give you the rough HTML and CSS.

Comment: Any thoughts to add to my current scenario? Same question, just moved along a bit with some new methods. 

I appreciated your answer, by the way, but opted to use the Anystretch plugin as the inconsistencies within the hand drawn art made it difficult to create a fluid compatible layout. This seems to work well, though!

Comment: Ended up going this route at the end! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Wanna check this one out?

You can adjust all the frames' width and it can also loads dynamic contents.

One DEMO http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/nested_simple.html

SOURCE http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm

Comment: This is definitely worth looking into! Not sure it's the answer yet, but I appreciate the tip :) Love me some jQuery fixes, too, so worth looking into.

Comment: Just put up some new thoughts into the original question, actually.

Answer (score -2):

I'd just use an iFrame to show the actual content, and then take the illustration and put it around it on the parent page. You could build "navigation" (back button? and working Page Titles?) into the illustration too, that would be pretty simple and pretty cool.

You'll probably want some JS involved to handle resizing of content (in the iframe) and the illustration will probably need to be split up a bit so parts can be resized properly?

Comment: `<iframes>` are a bad idea on so many levels, and they are so "web 1.0"

Comment: The aim is "when a user visits the actual website, they'll see the character's "screen" with the real design inside of it. In way, it's simulating a computer with a web design inside of my proper web design." Which means it'd be ideal to be able to navigate around this sub-website without breaking the illustion. I agree that iframes are a bad idea for most use cases, but this scenario seems like it would be well suited for them.

Comment: @Phillip ~ While `<iframe>`s do get some bad rap (personally, I hate them with a burning conviction), they *do* have their (very niched) uses. This might be one of them. Another (arguable) use is to provide a much more stringent encapsulation on a website's resources.

Comment: I'd thought about using an <iframe> but came to the same conclusion. Besides, I don't want to nest content, as stated earlier here. It doesn't need to be an actual fake-OS simulation, but it would certainly not be best to go this route. Thanks for the input, though!